# why we build opencl program twice?

Tags: opencl, gpu

I observed in a opencl program for amd platform that we need to build program twice. once using clBuildProgram...(); and another when we build the entire code. why we do this build twice?

Comment: This Q got deleted just as you fixed it (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519090/why-the-structure-size-is-being-reported-different-on-linux-and-windows) The answer is that your compiler on the Linux machine aligns doubles on 4 byte boundaries when targeting x86. But your Windows compiler aligns on 8 byte boundaries.

Answer (score 10):

In OpenCL host code compilation and kernel code compilation are two separate steps.

When you compile what you refer to as the entire code, you are essentially just compiling the host code, that is, the code that will orchestrate and control the execution of OpenCL kernels.

The kernel code that will be executed on an OpenCL capable device (CPU, GPU, DSP, FPGA, Accelerator ...) has then two main compilation options:

- You may include the actual OpenCL kernel source in your program as a separate .cl file or embed it as a string in the host code.  When using this compilation path, you create the `program` object passed to `clBuildProgram` with `clCreateProgramWithSource`. The host code can then use the online compiler **at runtime**, to compile the kernel for the desired architecture of the OpenCL capable device that you want to run the kernel on. The advantage of this is that you don't need to know beforehand (when creating your host program) what the architecture of the OpenCL device will be (Intel, AMD, Nvidia, ...). You may not even have the compiler for that architecture. The disadvantage is that your kernel source code will be visible, which is not desirable if you have valuable IP embedded in it.
- you may decide to compile the kernel(s) beforehand for all the OpenCL device architectures that you want to support, and ship the binaries for those kernels with your host code, rather than the kernel source. When using this compilation path, you create the `program` object passed to `clBuildProgram` with `clCreateProgramWithBinary`.

You may also want to have a look at the [SPIR specification](http://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-spir-12-provisional.pdf), which combines the benefits of both approaches and allows you to ship an intermediate representation of your kernels, so you don't have to have all the target OpenCL compilers nor do you have to ship the plain source code of your kernels.

Comment: +1, excellent explanation. thanks. (unfortunately i cannot upvote, perhaps not having sufficient points..)